# Os.walk - count files in same subdirectory of parent directories

Tags: python, filesystems, os.walk

I'm trying to count the number of files in a specific folder, throughout a large number of parent directories. Each Project contains the same folder structure:

```
C:/Projects
    2019
        Project A
            Communication
                Images
        Project B
            Communication
                Images
        ...
    2018
        ...
```

Below is my attempt

```
base_dir = 'C:/Projects/'
years = ['2019', '2018', '2017']
image_folder = '/Communication/Images'

project_list = []
for project in project_list:
    for year in years:
        target_folder = base_dir + year + project + image_folder
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
            total += len(files)

# Print to CSV etc
```

First, I need to get a list of all paths to the image folder. What I'm struggling with understanding (even to get an attempt to work) is that os.walk takes in root, dir, files. Can os.walk do exactly what I need without getting into possibly 3 for loops? There are a LOT of files which I intend to count so I want to make sure I'm not taking a hit on performance by structuring it like I have

Comment: Hi David, if one of these responses answered your question, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

Python3's `pathlib` is pretty slick for this sort of thing:

```
from pathlib import Path 

base_dir = Path('C:/Projects/')

# rglob = recursive glob; finds all files in all subdirectories
files_generator = base_dir.rglob("*")    

total_n_files = len(list(files_generator))
```

You could even get a dictionary with counts of files by `target_folder` (using the file structure in your question) with:

```
from collections import Counter

base_dir = Path('C:/Projects/')
file_counts = Counter(p.parent for p in base_dir.rglob("*"))
```

(second code snippet adapted from a couple examples at: https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Answer (score 0):

os.walk() doesn't take **in** root, dir, and file but actually spits them out.
To be more precise [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.walk) provides you a generator which you can loop on and get a 3-tuple (roots, dirs, files). You can be fine with the 3-tuple or you can unpack it directly using the format:

```
for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(TOP_FOLDER):
    ...
```

os.walk() automatically travels down into your folders tree starting from TOP_FOLDER. 
I'm unsure why you're doing 3 for loops. Unless I misunderstood your needs, the following should count all the files in base_dir

```
base_dir = 'C:/Projects/'
tot = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    tot += len(files)
```

Actually, if you don't need to keep track of the folders and subfolders paths you can suppress the first two elements of the unpacked tuple:

```
    for _, _, files in os.walk(base_dir):
        tot += len(files)
```